# spring data findBy return type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

What are the possible return types of spring data findBy methods? I haven't found any consolidated list anywhere.

like findByXXX can return

```
1) Entity
2) Optional<Entity>
3) List<Entity>
4) Stream<Entity>
```

and many more, but do we have a definite list?

Also, `List<Entity>` returns emptyList when no data found but `Stream<Entity>` returns null when no data found, so when you apply map/filter etc on stream, you get NPE.

Is there a better way to use Stream without causing NPE, other than physically checking null before calling stream functions.

Comment: Maybe `Collection<Entity>` instead of/along with `List<Entity>`

Answer (score 5):

Though a bit late, but the supported return types are documented here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-return-types

Generally, the return types could be any of the following categories:

1. a (Optional) single item, could be a primitive, wrapped, or object, or void
2. a collection of items, or paged list
3. a stream, Iterator, Mono/Flux, or those similar.
4. Future, or its variants

#### And, the complete list of currently supported return types:

> - void
> - Primitives
> - Wrapper types
> - T
> - Iterator
> - Collection
> - List
> - Optional
> - Option
> - Stream
> - Streamable
> - Types that implement Streamable and take a Streamable constructor or factory method argument
> - Vavr Seq, List, Map, Set
> - Future
> - CompletableFuture
> - ListenableFuture
> - Slice
> - Page
> - GeoResult
> - GeoResults
> - GeoPage
> - Mono
> - Flux
> - Single
> - Maybe
> - Flowable

Answer (score 4):

Your list of possible return type is corret. You can use too the type **Page** and **Slice** when you need pagination the result. See example:

```
Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);

Slice<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
```

*"The first method allows you to pass an org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable instance to the query method to dynamically add paging to your statically defined query. A Page knows about the total number of elements and pages available. It does so by the infrastructure triggering a count query to calculate the overall number. As this might be expensive depending on the store used, Slice can be used as return instead. A Slice only knows about whether there’s a next Slice available which might be just sufficient when walking thought a larger result set."* - See more in: [Spring Data Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters)

For another question, you can use Guava/Java 8 **Optional**. This way, your query method will return an Optional that contains the found object or an empty Optional. **Optional** is a way of replacing a nullable T reference with a non-null value, see example:

```
Optional<User> findById(Long id);
```

I hope I have help you. =)